# Splitting string at nearest white space to length into new row with all other data copied

Tags: python, string, split, data-cleaning

I am trying to find a way to split the long strings (9 words or 80 characters whatever works better for your solution) in a column of my DF and break them into two rows.

For example:

In [7]: a

Out[7]:

```
    var1                                                               var2 var3
0  'this is a long string that should break here but it keeps going'     1   a
1  'this string is a fine length'                                        2   b

In [8]: b
Out[8]: 
var1                                              var2 var3
0  'this is a really long string that should break' 1   a
1  'here but wow it keeps going'                    1   a
2  'this string is a fine length'                   2   b
```

I have found many options to split at a specific character but those will not apply here.

```
df.set_index(['var2', 'var3'])
   .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode())
   .reset_index()
```

But this is not easy (at least for me) to modify to s whole word break at a specific string length.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking look at [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) (part of standard library), consider following simple example, say requirement is to have 50 characters or less per line then you might use `textwrap.wrap` following way

```
import textwrap
s1 = 'this is a long string that should break here but it keeps going'
s2 = 'this string is a fine length'
splitted1 = textwrap.wrap(s1, width=50)
splitted2 = textwrap.wrap(s2, width=50)
print(splitted1)  # ['this is a long string that should break here but', 'it keeps going']
print(splitted2)  # ['this string is a fine length']
```